# How to form a box formation on a 2d grid no matter the amount of points

Tags: c#, math

On a 2d grid, given a `List` of positions with X amount of elements. How do I make sure these elements always get arranged as close as possible to a box formation?

i.e, given a list of 9 elements, form this:

```
o o o
o x o
o o o
```

given a list of 5 elements, form this:

```
o x o
o o
```

And so on.

```
//selection is a list of random positions on the grid, I click on the map and want them to move and form a box formation
Vector2Int origin = mousePosition;
List<Vector2Int> boxPositions = new List<Vector2Int>();
int rows = ?
int cols = ?

for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count; i++)
{
    //Calculate position
    boxPositions.Add(myNewlyCalculatedPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out that using the root of the total count of points will work.

```
            int total = selection.Count;
            int rows = Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Sqrt(total));

            for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
            {
                if (total <= 0)
                    break;

                for (int z = 0; z < rows; z++)
                {
                    if (total <= 0)
                        break;

                    positions.Add(adjustedWorldPos);

                    total--;
                }
            }
```